# Select all options from dropdown on button click using AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to select all values from a drop down of HTML on `ng-click`. Here is my HTML code

```
<select multiple ng-model="selectedToPostalCodes"
    ng-options="items.postalcode for items in toPostalCodes">
    <option style="display:none;"></option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Select All" ng-click="selectall()">
```

So I want the implementation of `selectall()` function.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this way:: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Upal_Roy/JB3Un/343/)

```
fiddleApp.controller('Main', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 $scope.toPostalCodes = [
        {postalcode:1, name:"Japan"},
        {postalcode:4, name:"USA"}
    ]; 
 $scope.selectedToPostalCodes = [];  
$scope.selectall = function(){        
     $scope.selectedToPostalCodes = []; 
     angular.forEach($scope.toPostalCodes, function(item){
         $scope.selectedToPostalCodes.push( item.postalcode);
     }); 
 }   
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
$scope.selectall = function() {
    var allOptions = [];
    // First get all codes as list
    angular.forEach($scope.toPostalCodes, function(item) {
        allOptions.push(item.postalcode);
    });

    // And then assign the values to the scope model
    $scope.selectedToPostalCodes = allOptions;
};
```

Comment: thats a good answer. but how user will know that he selected all the options? if we select an option it highlights to blue I also want to highlight all fields in select.

Comment: That should reflect automatically on the `<select>` tag as all are selected. Is that not happening?

Comment: Or you can display a small message and make that hide after a few seconds.